# Wordpress shortcode ouput via function

Tags: php, wordpress, function, shortcode

What is the best approach for a shortcode to get its output from another function. echo works but it generate the shortcode before all content. before ending file there is a php switch that I am loading different functions in base of which style selected. This is the function:
staticMarkup($titleRendered, $contentRendered, $feedbackRendered, $roleRendered, $companyRendered, $image_urlRendered, $slider, $color);

```html
<?php
add_shortcode('sample', 'sample_shortcode');

function sample_shortcode($atts)
 {
 global $tesio;
 $markup = '';

 // Attributes

 $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
  'style' => '',
  'testio_id' => '',
  'slider' => '',
  'colors' => '',
  'color' => '',
  'wide' => 'no',
  'bgcolor' => '',
  'dpadding' => '',
  'tpadding' => '',
  'spadding' => '',
  'instance' => 1
 ) , $atts);
 wp_enqueue_script('testio-front-js');
 wp_localize_script('testio-front-js', 'testio_var', $atts);
 $testio_id = $explodeID = $style = $slider = $colors = $bgcolor = $vpadding = $color = $wide = $colorContrast = '';
 $testio_id = $atts['testio_id'];
 $explodeID = explode(',', $testio_id);
 $style = $atts['style'];
 $slider = $atts['slider'];
 $colors = $atts['colors'];
 $bgcolor = $atts['bgcolor'];
 $dpadding = $atts['dpadding'];
 $tpadding = $atts['tpadding'];
 $spadding = $atts['spadding'];
 $color = $atts['color'];
 $wide = $atts['wide'];
 $testioAmount = count(explode(',', $testio_id));
 if (!empty($colors))
  {
  $colors = explode(',', $colors);
  }

 if (!empty($bgcolor))
  {
  $colorContrast = getContrast50($bgcolor);
  }

 static $uniqueID;
 if ($testio_id !== '')
  {
  if ($testio_id == 'all')
   {
   $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'testio_wp',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => - 1
   );
   }
    else
  if ($testioAmount > 1)
   {
   $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'testio_wp',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post__in' => $explodeID,
    'posts_per_page' => $testioAmount,
    'orderby' => 'post__in'
   );
   }
    else
  if ($testioAmount == 1)
   {
   $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'testio_wp',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'p' => $testio_id,
    'posts_per_page' => 1
   );
   }

  $posts = get_posts($args);
  $wrapperClass = 'staticWrap';
  $wideClass = '';
  $sliderClass = '';
  $masonryContainer = '';
  $masonryContainerClose = '';
  $backgroundStyle = '';
  $sliderMarkup = '';
  $sliderCloseMarkup = '';
  $wrapperClassExtra = '';
  $dataAttr = 'data-padding = ' . $dpadding . ',' . $tpadding . ',' . $spadding;
  switch ($style)
   {
  case 'static':
   if ($wide == 'yes')
    {
    $wideClass = ' wide';
    }

  default:
   break;
   }

  if ($testioAmount == 1)
   {
   $slider == 'no';
   $sliderContainer = '';
   }

  $markup.= '<div class="testioWrap ' . $wrapperClass . $wrapperClassExtra . '" ' . $backgroundStyle . ' data-id="' . $wrapperClass . $uniqueID . '" ' . $dataAttr . '>';
  $markup.= $sliderMarkup;
  $markup.= $masonryContainer;
  $x = 0;
  $colorClass = '';
  $postCount = '';
  foreach($posts as $post)
   {
   $titleRendered = $post->post_title;
   $contentRendered = $post->post_content;
   $idRendered = $post->ID;
   $feedbackRendered = get_field('testio_rate', $idRendered);
   $roleRendered = get_field('testio_role', $idRendered);
   $companyRendered = get_field('testio_company', $idRendered);
   $image_urlRendered = get_the_post_thumbnail($idRendered, 'thumbnail');
   if (!empty($colors))
    {
    $colorClass = $colors[$x % 5];
    }

   $x++;
   $postCount++;
   $freeMessage = '<div class="testio-notice"> Please get the pro version to unlock ' . $style . ' style <a href="http://testiowp.com" class="testio_btn">Upgrade</a></div>';
   switch ($style)
    {
   case "static":
    staticMarkup($titleRendered, $contentRendered, $feedbackRendered, $roleRendered, $companyRendered, $image_urlRendered, $slider, $color);
   default:
    break;
    }
   }

  $markup.= $masonryContainerClose;
  $markup.= $sliderCloseMarkup;
  $markup.= '</div>';
  return $markup;
  }
   else
  {
  $markup.= '<div class="testio">';
  $markup.= __('Please put an id to the shortcode', 'testio-wp');
  $markup.= '</div>';
  }

 $uniqueID++;
 }

?>
```

This is the codes inside the staticMarkup function:

```html
<?php
function staticMarkup($title, $content, $feedback, $role, $company, $image_url, $slider, $color){
        $markup ='';
        $colorStyle = 'style="color: '.$color.';"';
        if($slider == 'yes'){
            $markup .= '<div>';
        }

        $markup .= '<div class="testio testioStatic" data-color="'.$color.'">';
            $markup .= '<div class="leftBorder"></div>';
            if($image_url !== '' ){
                $markup .= '<div class="thumbnailWrapper">';
                $markup .= $image_url;
                $markup .= '</div>';
            }
            $markup .= feedbackMarkup($feedback);
            $markup .= '<div class="testio-content">';
                $markup .= '<p>'.$content.'</p>';
            $markup .= '</div>';
            $markup .= '<h3 class="testio-name" '.$colorStyle.'>~ ' .$title. '</h3>';
            $markup .= '<h4 class="testio-role">' .$role. ' <span class="role-divider icon-at-sign"></span> ' .$company. '</h4>';
            
        $markup .= '</div>';
        if($slider == 'yes'){
            $markup .= '</div>';
        }
        echo $markup;
    }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the staticMarkup function replace:

```
echo $markup;
```

with:

```
return $markup;
```

This will return the variable where it has been positioned/called as opposed to above all content.

Comment: is it correct to return $markup 2 times? once in shortcode itself and the inner function!